# google maps and some styles needs a couple of times refreshing browser

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

I implemented google maps on my site, and it happens something a bit odd. Sometimes, when I load the page, the map does not appear, but if I refresh it does. But sometimes it needs to be refreshed a couple of times before it appears, and it seems to happen with some styles, that the first time I load the page, some styles aren't applied but when I load, everything looks fine.

I don't know what I should check. My boss just told me to check the debugging and I have no idea what does he mean.

That's my head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Decorum Wines</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/decorumStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/decorumStyles_custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/pager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
    <script>       
       var google;

        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5235958, -0.219394, 17);
            var mapProp = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'hello world'
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());

        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

And this is my bottom section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/toggleBrowse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    // Add a script element as a child of the body
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "home.php";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    // Check for browser support of event handling capability
    if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I have looked at the order of my external files, but I think it is alright, however, definitely it is something not working 100% fine as it behaves a bit odd as I explained.

Any comments will be welcome!

Thank you all!

Comment: debugging  -- means, open the browser console to check for errors  --- http://help.gawker.com/customer/portal/articles/1569034-how-do-i-open-my-browser-s-javascript-console-

Answer (score 0):

1. this line has to be removed:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
   ```

   you load the maps-API asynchronously, `initialize` will be called automatically(because you use it as `callback`-parameter). Furthermore it may happen that `google.maps.event` isn't available yet at the time when this line will be executed.
2. It's not clear what home.php will do(if it's related to the issue), but when it will do something that is based on the map that will be created in `initialize` you should load this script at the end of `initialize`

   ```
   <script>       

   function initialize() {
       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5235958, -0.219394);
       var mapProp = {
           zoom: 15,
           center: myLatlng,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myLatlng,
           map: map,
           title: 'hello world'
       });
       downloadJSAtOnload();
   }       

   </script>
   ```

This part of your 2nd script has to be removed too:

```
// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Comment: thank you for answering!! although I'm still having the same issue, it works absolutely fine in firefox, chrome and safari but not in explorer... :s in any of the versions!

Comment: Is this page online(can you share a link)?